# Suggested Form Addon

Tags: forms, devdemon-forms

I have used the DevDemon form addon since EE2 but its basically dead at this point. I reported more than one bug to the developer over a year and they don't bother to fix anything. I don't think it will be upgraded to EE4 either and the last update was over a 1.5 years ago.

I would just buy the one from Solspace but it has something missing that I really need and most forms have today.

The form logic that is based on JavaScript. For example, hide field X if user fills out data on field A or show field B if email field is completed. This allows you to show or hide and change the form based on what the user is filling out. I also need regex checks.

The DevDemon form has this but its extremely buggy and at this point not even working with EE3 anymore correctly. Neither is the multiform feature and I don't think there is future for it with EE4 either. I only use the module for more advanced forms as the build in form functions from EE work fine for basic things.

Is there any alternative for more complex forms today? Pricing is not a problem.

Comment: Much of what you are asking (form show/hide dependencies) are easily done via JavaScript by yourself on the front end. If it was buggy in DevDemon anyways, you are better off whipping up JS yourself to show/hide and validate fields on the front end yourself. Also, Solspace Freeform has extension hooks, so you can enforce the same validation on the back end as well.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not referring to data validation on POST submission. This is already done on the server side back end and not JS which would be insecure. Its just a visual trick that hides or changes the form fields based on the checked options, or fields interaction. For example you can show a HTML warning if a field is missing (before submission) or show another field if a checkbox is on/off. This allows for very complex forms. If I was that great at JavaScript I would probably not need an add-on. The purpose of those add-ons is to let anyone create forms quickly.

Comment: Well this is a developer forum, so I recommended the developer solution. I'm sorry, I don't think there is any out-of-the-box solutions for you right now, and you'll likely need to hire a developer. DevDemon is unlikely to make a big comeback, Parscale is now Trump's campaign manager for the 2020 run so consider DevDemon not a near-future option.

Comment: I was aware he is busy with Trump but someone else seems to manage DevDemon for him. What JS library or code can I use to achieve similar things with forms. Just jquery?

Comment: Depends on exactly what you want to do. It's pretty easy, albeit tedious, to just use jQuery to write a procedural set of watchers on your form elements, to show/hide other elements. And yeah there is someone tending DevDemon, but if you look at the blog entries it is pretty damn questionable about DevDemons future and EE3/4 support for their main products. But that is a personal opinion. If you need to change a form field based on a previous field, try this: https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_chained

Comment: Just to pile on to what @jrothafer has been saying: we use FreeForm and jquery to achieve what you are describing... If this radio button is selected hide this field and show this one... etc.

Answer (score 1):

Solspace Freefom is a powerful form add-on. EE4 compatible, great support and updated frequently

https://solspace.com/expressionengine/freeform/